# Getting the date from DATETIME. mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I wish to query for

```
MyDate= '2013-07-08'
```

From the following records

```
MyDate
2013-07-08 09:15:21
2013-07-08 09:15:48
2013-07-09 09:20:39
```

I have come up with some ugly stuff :

```
MyDate > '2013-07-07 23:59:59' AND MyDate < '2013-07-09 00:00:01'
```

Is there a better/simple/elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to isolate the date portion of the datetime expression.

```
WHERE DATE(MyDate) = '2013-07-08'
```

Comment: Note that wrapping the column in a function disables MySQL from making efficient use of an index on the MyDate column.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks a ton for that.   Its those little tidbits that get glossed over when you are just trying to "Go live yesterday"

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to compare dates use this. If not disregard.

This may not be the most perfect way but, i have used this in the past. Basically i would format both dates so they can be used with a greater than or equal to statement(YEAR/MONTH/DAY).

SELECT * FROM  table
WHERE MyDate > DATE_FORMAT(2013-07-07 23:59:59,  '%Y%m%y') 
AND MyDate < DATE_FORMAT(2013-07-09 00:00:01,  '%Y%m%y')

Answer (score 0):

The normative pattern to matching the date portion of a DATETIME in a predicate (e.g. a WHERE clause) is:

```
 WHERE MyDate >= '2013-07-08'
   AND MyDate <  '2013-07-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

When no time component is supplied, MySQL uses midnight as the time component, so there's no need to supply a time component of midnight.  The bare column references in the predicate allow for MySQL to consider making efficient range scan on an index on the MyDate column.

For completeness, we'll note that it's also possible to use a ETWEEN operator. But because the "high side" comparison with the BETWEEN is a "less than or equal to", to get just values with date component of a single day, we'd need to back up the smallest fraction of time, which for a DATETIME is a single second:

```
 WHERE MyDate BETWEEN '2013-07-08'
                  AND '2013-07-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL -1 SECOND
```

(If we had a datatype that had a finer resolution, we'd want to step back from the next day by that smallest unit of resolution.)

To avoid that issue, how fine a resolution is on a given datetime/timestamp datatype (more of an issue with other databases such as SQL Server than MySQL), I just have a preference of the former pattern, using a predicate like:

```
dateexpr >= midnight and dateexpr < midnight of next day
```

That's unambiguous, and there's no possible way to have a time value of `23:59:59.997` to be missed, and no possibility of getting exactly at midnight of the next day included.

Because the default time component, when none is supplied, is midnight, the first query predicate is equivalent to:

```
 WHERE MyDate >= '2013-07-08 00:00:00'
   AND MyDate <  '2013-07-08 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

I think all those extra zeros to explicitly specify a time value of midnight are unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Wouldn't BETWEEN be better in this situation?

Comment: @edwardmp: the BETWEEN does a <= comparison rather than a `<` on the high side, so it would also "match" `'2013-07-09'`. If we wanted to use BETWEEN, it should be `BETWEEN '2013-07-08' AND '2013-07-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL -1 SECOND`